# How to get long titles in the toc, and short titles in the headers?

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

Usually, when I want to reduce the size of some of my titles in the headers, I use [a short title in brackets]. But, this time, I'd like to use long titles in the TOC, but the headers have to be short. How could I achieve this? This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,12pt,twoside,openright,a4paper]{book}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.49998pt}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-2.49998pt}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{setspace}
 \linespread{1.1}

\usepackage[left=5.5cm,right=5.5cm,top=6.5cm,bottom=6.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titling}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\itshape}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize\itshape}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\itshape}


\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{3pt}%espace entre chapitres
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for chapters


\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[numberedbib,nosectionbib]{apacite}
\usepackage[makeindex]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=npr, title=Index des noms] 
\makeindex[name=mat, title=Index des matières]

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
% We don't want chapter and section numbers
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CE]{\textit{A name}} % even pages: chapter title
\fancyhead[CO]{\textit\leftmark} % odd pages: book title


%%%%%%%%%%%%Pas de N° de chapitres%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
    {\centering\Large\bfseries}% format of chapter
    {\large\normalfont\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\enskip\thechapter}% format of the label
    {.5\baselineskip}{} % space between the two
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{25pt}{35pt} % spaces around \chapter{}, {left}{before}{after}
 
%\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  %{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%épigraphe%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{}% Not necessary...
\newenvironment{chapquote}[2][2em]
  {\setlength{\@tempdima}{#1}%
   \def\chapquote@author{#2}%
   \parshape 1 \@tempdima \dimexpr\textwidth-2\@tempdima\relax%
   \itshape}
  {\par\normalfont\hfill---\ 
 \chapquote@author\hspace{\@tempdima}\par\bigskip\par\bigskip}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%Numérotation en chiffres arabes%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\frontmatter{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmatterfalse
  %\pagenumbering{roman}% Don't reset
}
\renewcommand\mainmatter{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmattertrue
  %\pagenumbering{arabic}% Don't reset
}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}
\title{A title}
\author{A name}
\date{}
\maketitle


\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Sommaire}
\tableofcontents
\frontmatter

\mainmatter


\chapter[A chapter whose the title is short]{A chapter which has a very very very long title as you can see}
\lipsum
\chapter{A section which has also a very very very long title as you can see}
\lipsum


\backmatter
\chapter{Conclusion}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The way to go, since you use `titlesec`, is to load it with option `[toctitles]`.  The optional argument of `chapter` will be used only in the headers (see §3.7 of the documentation).

Comment: I  tried this, but it does not work as you say: \usepackage[toctitles]{titlesec}. Is this code right?

Comment: That is OK. I never tried this option, but perhaps it is linked to your using `tocloft` for the formatting of your table of contents. Anyway, `titlesec` has a companion package for that: `titletoc`. You should try to see first if it works with the default formatting. Also, another question: did you compile at least twice with this option?

Comment: I removed tocloft, but it does not change anything. Even using \usepackage{titletoc}, it does not work at all.

Comment: `toctitles` optoin seems to work for sections, not chapters - see workaround at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498592/table-of-contents-to-take-full-name-of-sections-while-header-and-footer-take-sho/498595#498595 . Alternatively, use `\chaptermark`: `\chapter{VERY VERY VERY VERY LONG TITLE} \chaptermark{SHORT TITLE}` - see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/216144/classicthesis-short-title-not-appear-in-table-of-content-in-lyx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `memoir` class (a superset of `book`, `report`, ...) has two optional arguments for division titles. For example:

```
\section[toc-title][head-title]{title}
```

where `toc-title` is put in the ToC, `head-title` is put in the page headers, and `title` is the section's title in the body of the document.

All the division macros from `\chapter` through `\subparagraph` have the same capabilities.

Comment: It works. Does the memoir class offer the same capabilities of the book class? With this solution, I can't use tocloft anymore.

Comment: The `memoir` class includes, and extends, the capabilities of the `tocloft` package, albeit with some minor changes in the macro names. For example `\cftsectiondotsep` instead of `cftsecdotsep`. In general division names like `\section`, or captions, are spelled out in full instead of shortened. Like `cftfigurefont` instead of `\cftfigfont`.